# Are there different kinds of SATA power connectors, and if so, what terminology do I need to distinguish them?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, sata, cable

I have two power cables that I'm trying to use to hook up multiple hard drives in an Unraid system. Both look superficially like this:

[image]

...with a 6-pin connector like this that goes into the power supply:

[image]

...and three connectors like this that hook up to the hard drives:

[image]

One cable works, the other doesn't. The difference seems to be exact form of the 6-pin connector that plugs into the power supply. The connector on the left is from the cable that works. The right does not.

[image]

Each of these has slightly different pin shapes, and each has a different no-connect pin. I'm trying to buy another cable like the one on the left, but I have no idea what terminology to use to make the distinction I need to make. When I search online for cables like these, and when I look at the manuals for the drives or my power supply, I get no help, nothing that even suggests that the world acknowledges that these two incompatible forms for very similar looking cables is a matter of concern.

Any assistance clearing this up will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The SATA power connector is standardized. The other end of the power cable can be whatever is needed to make a connection. This other end has absolutely no standards.

Comment: Then how to I specify when buying a cable the configuration I need for the power supply end of the cable?

Comment: The only safe solution is to buy cables made for the power supply, exact model only, directly from the manufacturer. cables can be incompatible amongst models of the same brand

Comment: The Apevia ATX-GX650W I purchased came with one power cable for powering three SATA devices. Not realizing these cables weren't standardized, and needing to power two more drives for my Unraid drive array, I tried to use a similar cable left over from another system. That obviously didn't work! On Apevia's website, although they sell other power cables, they apparently don't sell extra compatible 3-Sata power cables, or say anything about where you can get them. I'm settling for a SATA power cable that plugs into an available 4-pin Molex connector, rather than directly into the power supply.